# How do I find the next ID?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, design-patterns

I am trying to find out the best way to implement nextId() in a Javascript app that issues unique IDs for its objects. If it matters, it's a program that I am doing as a learning experience that's pure JS, HTML, and CSS (no libraries, frameworks, DBMS, etc.). I saw a similar question on here on SO (although I wasn't able to find it again for the link) with answers that included not only storing a list of possible ids paired with a boolean value to determine if the id is used, but also storing deleted ids in a recycling list to use for future objects that need it. I think the latter option sounds better, but I'm sure there are even more ways to do it. Does anyone know if there is a pattern, algorithm, or otherwise best practice for this task?

EDIT:
I would like to allow users to share data at some point soon in the application's life, so IDs that already exist would likely become an issue at some point. I would like the IDs to be permanent as I will be persisting data with LocalStorage. A simple integer will work which I will prefix with a letter or two to identify the type of object. It would also be nice to fill in the holes, so the integer doesn't get too high when users use it long-term (wishful thinking).

Also, all objects are constructed from strings at the beginning of the program (I know it's insane).

Comment: The ID must only be unique per client? Do they have to be persistent across sessions? Would a simple sequential integer identity work? We need more information on how these IDs will be used.

Comment: Very good point! I would like to allow users to share data at some point soon in the application's life, so IDs that already exist would likely become an issue at some point. I would like the IDs to be permanent as I will be persisting data with LocalStorage. A simple integer will work which I will prefix with a letter or two to identify the type of object. It would also be nice to fill in the holes, so the integer doesn't get too high when users use it long-term (wishful thinking).

Comment: Well, how to you expect to share data across users if you have no server? Will all clients use the same machine?

Comment: Honestly, until I have my app more fleshed out, I am using toString and fromString to store and construct objects. I planned to copy and paste the strings using the clipboard to and from text messages, emails, etc.

Comment: I know I still have a lot to learn about asking questions on here, but I want to thank you all for your patience and time in answering this question for me. It has definitely scratched my itch. Hopefully, all the good stuff you guys wrote helps someone else, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need an id that is unique per the lifetime of a page, you can use a simple monotomically increasing counter in the page:

```
var getUniqueID = (function() {
    var cntr = 0;
    return function() {
        return cntr++;
    };
})();

var idA = getUniqueID();
var idB = getUniqueID();
```

---

To make sure your ids are unique among all users is a taller task.  Without involving a central server that coins unique ids for you, the general concept here is to create an id that is a combination of three things:

1. A token that is unique to the user (like a userID)
2. A token that is guaranteed to be unique for the session (like what we have above)
3. A random value.

Done right, there can never be a collision between two different users (because the userID is in the id) and the counter makes it so no user ever generates the same id twice in the same session and the random value makes the odds of a user generating the same id themselves in the same session extremely small.

```
var getGUID = (function() {
    var cntr = 0;
    return function(userID) {
        var rand = Math.random().toString().replace(".", "");
        return userID + "_" + rand + "_" + cntr++;
    };
})();

var idA = getGUID(myUserID);
var idB = getGUID(myUserID);
```

---

Note: this is the simpler approach on GUID generation that assumes you already have a userID.  There is a whole lot of research and literature on various strategies for generating a GUID which you can certainly read a lot more about if you want something beyond this.  Some references on the topic:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier

http://betterexplained.com/articles/the-quick-guide-to-guids/

http://www.uddi.org/pubs/draft-leach-uuids-guids-01.txt
```

Comment: I like this minimal approach. It fits well with everything else that I am doing in my vanilla app. I plan to use Google and Facebook APIs to allow people to share when I have the time to figure it all out down the road. Do you have any tips or advice on how to avoid ID conflicts among small groups of users (friends, families, small businesses, etc.) using this approach?.

Comment: @dsgfloss - I added an idea to my answer for a globally unique id (often referred to as a GUID).

Comment: Would it be better factor it into an object like {'uid':'123','id':'234'}. In case, I decide to outsource generating an ID to other code in the future?

Comment: @dsgfloss - I'm not aware of any advantage to putting it in an object.  I guess it depends upon whether you have methods that will want to operate on it.  In pretty much every case I've seen a GUID is just a string and it works fine as that.  If it's just a string, it shouldn't matter if you change the way it's generated sometime in the future as long as your new mechanism is compatible with GUIDs already generated.  Plus the GUID generally has to be a string (or some sequence of bytes) in order to share it across a network anyway.  You shouldn't care what's in a GUID just that it's unique.

Comment: Just to be clear: Your first approach, getUniqueID(), guarantees uniqueness, while the second approach, getGUID(), guarantees uniqueness to be extremely likely. Correct? If so, I could prefix the result of getUniqueID() with a userID just as well, right?

Comment: @dsgfloss - The first approach guarantees uniqueness only within the scope of the currently running web page on this browser.  Other times that web page is loaded in the same or different browsers will use the same ids.  The second solution generates uniqueness in the world (assuming you have a userID that is also unique in the world).  Adding a userID to `getUniqueID()` only gets you part way there because two web pages loaded by the same user can generate conflicting user ids.  That's why the random value is added to make the odds of a conflict extremely low.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the use case, I like to create a complex unique id:

```
function newGUID(){

        var result = '';
        var hexcodes = "0123456789abcdef".split("");

        for (var index = 0; index < 32; index++) {
            var value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16);

            switch (index) {
                case 8:
                    result += '-';
                    break;
                case 12:
                    value = 4;
                    break;

            }
            result += hexcodes[value];
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: So, you've got a nice simple elegant solution for a random 32-digit hex ID. I'm wondering, though, why stop at hex? The resultant ID is a string. So, why stop at 'f' when you could go all the way to 'z' and then proceed with 'A' all the way to 'Z' and so on. Wouldn't we be making it even more complex and unique?

Comment: I honestly have no idea. I've found that function a long time ago in my most novice days. Very good throw-in indeed.

Comment: I accepted jfriend00's answer because it showed me how to resolve conflicts between users. I really like your idea of writing a function that generates random numbers one digit at a time, though. Now that this is worked out with a little more effort I could change the generated id number from base 16 (0-f) to base 62 (0-Z). That should increase the probability of uniqueness exponentially even if it takes a few more ms to generate the number. I will try to remember to come back when I have more reputation to upvote this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use UUIDs as IDs. [There's one answer here in SO where you can generate UUIDs in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-javascript). UUIDs are usually enough to be used as IDs. Just to be sure that the id isn't a dupe, you can have an object whose keys are the used IDs. As IDs are generated, you can keep track of them by adding them in the object. You can then look them up by doing `obj.hasOwnProperty(id)`.

You can do it like

```
var idStorage = {};
var id;

// generate ID that's unique and hasn't been used
do{
  id = guid();
} while (idStorage.hasOwnProperty(id));

idStorage[id] = true;

// ID is usable
```

Also, IDs are supposed to be unique. They should never be reused at all.

Comment: You're the first to mention that a reused ID is not unique. So, I'll scrap that idea and just go with incrementing a counter. Or would UUID/GUID solve the problem of sharing an object with another user who already has one with that ID? Or does it just make it astronomically unlikely and that's accepted?

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS has a very simply approach to generating unique IDs: just increment a global counter. From [`src/Angular.js`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/6502ab09774e1ac310da90c9e1c49fb0cd652d66/src/Angular.js#L314):

```
var uid = 0;

// ...

/**
 * A consistent way of creating unique IDs in angular.
 *
 * Using simple numbers allows us to generate 28.6 million unique ids per second for 10 years before
 * we hit number precision issues in JavaScript.
 *
 * Math.pow(2,53) / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365 / 10 = 28.6M
 *
 * @returns {number} an unique alpha-numeric string
 */
function nextUid() {
    return ++uid;
}
```

Of course, you should choose a solution depending on *what time frame* the generated IDs should be unique. The above solution will generate IDs which are unique for one session of one web page. For a simple single-page application (which is Angular's use case), this will do just fine. If you need them to be unique across multiple page loads, or unique for the same user, you'll need to persist the `uid` for a bit longer (in a cookie or in a database). If they need to be unique for a longer time, you might also need to look into longer IDs with more than `2^53` possible values.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [UUID v4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) since these IDs would always be unique in any circumstance (no additional logic to check if these ids are in use or to recicle old ones), just issue a new id whenever you need one.

Very simple implementation in JS as follows:

```js
function generateUUID(){
    return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
        var r = Math.random()*16|0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8);
        return v.toString(16);
    });
}

$(function() {
  $('button').bind('click', function() {
     $('input').val(generateUUID());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" style="width: 350px;"/><button>GENERATE NEW ID</button>
```

Comment: How can we be sure that this won't produce the same ID twice? Like "I definetly won't have to double-check this never under any circumstances" sure?

Comment: From the link I provided; "The number of possible UUIDs is 340,282,366,920,938,463,463,374,607,431,768,211,456 (1632 or 2 128), or about 3.4 × 1038." - If by generating them randomly you get the same ID twice then you are such an unlucky person!!! Actually, in practice you will never have this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's a bit unclear what you expect from these ids, however if you only want a unique id per type of entity in your system and your data must only live in memory, then you could use the following approach:

Note: I saw from the comments you wanted a prefix which represents the entity.

```
function identitySequence(base) {
    var id = base || 0;

    return function () {
        return ++id;
    };
}

//Lets say you had some sort of repository for every entity
function InMemoryUserRepository(nextId) {
    this._nextId = nextId;
}

InMemoryUserRepository.prototype = {
    constructor: InMemoryUserRepository,

    get nextId() { return 'user-' + this._nextId(); }

    //other operations, like save...
};


var userRepository = new InMemoryUserRepository(identitySequence());

userRepository.nextId; //user-1
```

Now, lets say you wanted your id sequence to be persistent in the `localStorage`, here's what you could do (extending the above code):

```
var userRepository = new InMemoryUserRepository(localStorageIdentitySequence('userIdSeq'));

userRepository.nextId; //user-1

//Reload page

userRepository.nextId; //user-2


function localStorageIdentitySequence(storageKey) {
    var next = identitySequence(+localStorage.getItem(storageKey));

    return function () {
        return +(localStorage[storageKey] = next());
    };
}
```

This works fine for a single machine, however if you want a unique id generator that will generate unique IDs across machines, then this approach will not work. You would have to generate the ID from a server that can be accessed by all clients, or you can generate a GUID on the client instead. There would be no way to know if the GUID was already generated by another client, but that would be very unlikely.